# Ways to get to thread created in SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.createThread(Runnable runnable)

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In my application using Spring Batch 3.0.1 I need to get access to the thread created by *SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.createThread(Runnable runnable)* before it is started in *doExecute*.

This needs to be done to attach security context stuff to the newly created thread.

Of course I could extend SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor and use this class, but that seems a crude solution.
I tried using Spring AOP and interceptors, but cannot intercept the right method.

Any ideas?

Edit:

```
protected void doExecute(Runnable task) {
    Thread thread = (this.threadFactory != null ? this.threadFactory.newThread(task) : createThread(task));
    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the correct way to handle this type of behavior would be to create your own `ThreadFactory` and pass that to the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`.  That would allow you access to the threads as they are being created.

You can read more about the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html

You can read more about the `ThreadFactory` here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html

Comment: Hmm, that was one of my initial thoughts, but _SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.threadFactory_ is not accessed, but _createThread_ invoked:
    protected void doExecute(Runnable task) {
  Thread thread = (this.threadFactory != null ? this.threadFactory.newThread(task) : createThread(task));
  thread.start();
    }
Or am I missing something?